# Streaming: tumbling window vs microbatching

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing

How is tumbling window of 5 secs in stream processing different from microbatch of 5 secs when microbatching? Both have a non-overlapping window of 5 secs during which they process the records and then move on.

I understand that there is this notion of time in stream processing: event, ingestion and processing time. Can we infer that stream processing using microbatching is nothing but stream processing using tumbling window with either ingestion time or processing time?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding they are quite similar from the point of view of results. They will allow to process some parts of data from the given period of time.

You are right with the Spark, due to the design limitations Spark Streaming reads some very small portion of data using given duration.

In my opinion the biggest difference between them is the purpose. Microbatching in Spark is used to limit the consuming data from the source. But Windows in Flink are used for processing data, they are created after the reading, so they do not really influence the pace of reading by the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

After researching more, here is my conclusion

- Earlier versions of Spark at least 1.6, as far as my knowledge is concerned (*feel free to correct me*), the concept of stream processing was based on microbatching where stream processing was handled as a special case of batch so that a stream could be dealt in microbatches of finite (very small) time duration.
- Tumbling window is a part of the evolved stream processing model (where data keeps entering a gigantic unbounded table and where, batch is treated as a special case of stream processing) and it works by:

  1. blocking out the "past" of the unbounded gigantic window/table
  2. and **then** looking forward to the inbound data to this gigantic window in a finite time duration into the future say 10 seconds
  3. processing it
  4. go back to step 1

So microbatching as a blackbox is very similar to tumbling window but the difference really is in the underlying architecture/design/approach that was adopted to implement window processing.

**Sources:**

- Designing Data Intensive Applications by Martin Klepmann
- http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-flink-streaming-part-2/

Comment: There is structured streaming as well, in or out of scope of your question?